# Get int from char[] of bytes

Tags: c, pointers

I have a file that I read into a char array.

The char array now holds a certain number of bytes, now if I know the file stored a 32bit integer in little endian at position say 0x8, how do I retrieve it from the char array?

```
FILE * file = fopen("file");
char buffer[size];
fread(buffer,1,size,file);
int = buffer[0x8]; // What should I do here?
// I imagine it involves some strange pointer
// arithmetic but I can't see what I should do,
// casting to int just takes the first byte,
// casting to (int *) doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to cast it like so:

```
int foo = *((int *) &buffer[0x8]);
```

Which will first cast the spot to a int pointer and the dereference it to the int itself.

[watch out for byte-ordering across different machine types though; some do high bytes first some do low]

And just to make sure the example is well understood, here's some code showing the results:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    char buffer[14] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 };
    int foo = *((int *) &buffer[0x8]);
    int bar = (int) buffer[0x8];

    printf("raw: %d\n", buffer[8]);
    printf("foo: %d\n", foo);
    printf("bar: %d\n", bar);
}
```

And the results from running it:

```
raw: 8
foo: 185207048
bar: 8
```

Comment: @cnicutar are you sure? `buffer[0x8]` is dereferencing (buffer + offset). It returns a value, not a pointer. Casting the value to an int pointer would point you who knows where..

Comment: @cnicutar, no it's not. It's in fact required.  Watch out for any alignment requirements your machine might have if you use this method.

Comment: buffer[0x8] will return the single byte at the 8th position in the buffer.  &buffer[0x8] will return the memory location of the 8th byte in the buffer, which is what needs to be cast.  You don't want to dereference the number at buffer 8.

Comment: @Carl Norum Yup, I was wrong :-) Of course it's required (for some reason I read `buffer` instead of `buffer[0x8]`).

Answer (score 4):

The "easy" way, assuming the array contains a byte of the same endianness as your machine, and that there aren't any special alignment requirements, is:

```
int x = *(int *)&buffer[8];
```

If you do have an endianness difference, you'll need to handle that.  If there's an alignment problem (or even potentially an alignment problem), you should extract the bytes one by one:

```
int x = buffer[8] + (buffer[9] << 8) + (buffer[10] <<  16) + (buffer[11] << 24);
```

Or possibly the other direction if the endianness is the other way.

Comment: +1. I just want to add that `*((int*)(buffer + 8))` would be the same.   It is most likely that you have **little-endian** machine - Intel or AMD...

Answer (score 1):

Endianess conversion of a 4byte value is done by changing the two words of that value (16bit), so the less efficient but readable way would be (if data is big endian encoded):

```
int val = 0x00000000;
char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val);
*ptr = buffer[0x0a];
ptr++;
*ptr = buffer[0x0b];
ptr++;
*ptr = buffer[0x08];
ptr++;
*ptr = buffer[0x09];
ptr++;
```

But there are many many other ways to do it like structs, memcpy... depending on what is your goal (performace, readability,...)

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

```
int *list = (int*)buffer;
int n = fread(buffer, 1, size, file);
for (int i=0; i< n/sizeof(int); i++)
  printf("%d\n", list[i]);
```